# convert formal argument to local variable in LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc

I am doing a project on LLVM.

I'm trying to make a pass:

For a function,
if the arguments(parameters) are constants,
it will make a new function that the constants are 
converted to a local variable,
and deleted from arguments.

For example:

```
void main(){
    c=foo(a,b);
    d=foo(a,100);
}

double foo(x,y){return x+y;}
```

will get optimized into:

```
void main(){
    c=foo(a,b);
    d=foo1(a);
}  

double foo(x,y){return x+y;}
double foo1(x){
    int y=100;
    return x+y;
}
```

To do this, I'm trying to make a new local variable
and then using `replaceAllUsesWith` function.

But I can't seem to allocate a new local variable.

I did try defining `new Value*` but when I assign it to the argument,
it becomes same pointer as the argument, which makes `replaceAllUsesWith` function useless.

Is there a way to allocate (in the memory) a new local variable in type of `Value*`?

Comment: Show your attempted code.